# Using Like with strings

Tags: mysql

I count rows where title is:

```
this-is-the-title
```

And if count is greater than 0 I append the count to the title and insert:

```
this-is-the-title-1
```

When inserting again I will need to check again but the where title = 'this is the title' will not catch any titles with appended numbers.

So I try:

```
LIKE 'this-is-the-title%'
```

This works but now it would also pick up any titles such as:

```
this-is-the-title-extra-string
```

How can I query the table so that I can count the number of instances of 'this-is-the-title' and any subsequent 'this-is-the-title-nth

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where column REGEXP '^this-is-the-title(-[0-9]+)?$'
```

Regular expressions are an ok solution for things like that. The question mark says that the trailing group is optional, i.e. it will match w/o it and [0-9]+ means one or more digit.
^ at the beginning means match at the beginning of line, $ means match at the end.  Together they ensure the full string match.

Comment: Thanks but this still picks up strings like: this-is-the-title-extra-string

Comment: that is a meaningless question.  There is only one way to tell -- measure the performance for your specific task.

Comment: Add second condition `column LIKE 'this-is-the-title%'` if you have an index on column -  it will help you to improve performance of query.